# многоуровневый запрос в базу mysql

Tags: php, mysql

есть 3 таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category_typeadverts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type_adverts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_title` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

как составить запрос таким образом, или как сделать так с помощью обработчика чтоб выбрать из таблицы type_adverts все записи и для каждой этой записи выбрать id и  title (один элемент может содержать несколько строк из таблицы category) из таблицы category, тогда как связаны эти две таблицы в третьей category_typeadverts

Answer (score 0):

Чем не подошел вариант просто всё приджойнить друг к другу?

```
SELECT ta.*, category.*
FROM type_adverts ta JOIN category_typeadverts ct ON(ta.id = ct.id_type) 
JOIN category ON (category.id = ct.id_category);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7e211/1

Comment: тем что мне нужно было поле type_title вывести только 1 раз а не как у Вас в таблице

Comment: я решил этот вопрос двумя разными запросами и соединил две выборки, конечно без цикла не обошлось, не знаю насколько это правильно

Comment: @vkt можно в один. добавить group by по уникальному полю. тайтл в вашем случае. и group_concat по полю, которое имеет несколько значений для одного тайтла. значения будут в одну строку через запятую.